# Correctly fetch ViewController interfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, autorotate

I am using the following code to retrieve interface orientation of custom `UIViewController` (which is not a navigation/tabview controller).

```
   public var windowOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
       return view.window?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation ?? .unknown
   }
```

However, under some conditions, this code gives incorrect orientation while the deprecated `-[UIViewController interfaceOrientation]` gives correct results. Specifically, this happens when I have a custom logic to return `supportedInterfaceOrientations` on startup of the app where I wait for some events to happen before enabling autorotation. What is the correct way of retrieving interface orientation in that case.

Comment: How about calculating the ratio between width and height of view when overriding `viewWillTransition`? Did you try it?

Comment: `viewWillTransition` is not called at the startup. To be more precise, I am holding the iPhone in portrait mode, starting the app, the root view controller returns only `.landscapeRight` in the `supportedInterfaceOrientations`. The view controller `interfaceOrientation` is correctly `.landscapeRight` but `windowOrientation` above is returning `.portrait`